# Accessing shared Google Drive folder using service account through API

Tags: javascript, authentication, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I would like to access a public google drive folder and get all the images from it. This works, but I would like to be able to enter without having to login in a popup. I read that you can actually do this by using the .json file from a service account. But I haven't seen any code for this approach. Where and what should I change in this code? (I'm including the whole code because I don't know exactly where to initiate this service account authentication.)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Google Drive Images</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My Google Drive Images</h1>
        <div id="image-container"></div>

        <!--Add buttons to initiate auth sequence and sign out-->
        <button id="authorize_button" onclick="handleAuthClick()">Authorize</button>
        <button id="signout_button" onclick="handleSignoutClick()">Sign Out</button>

        <pre id="content" style="white-space: pre-wrap;"></pre>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        /* exported gapiLoaded */
        /* exported gisLoaded */
        /* exported handleAuthClick */
        /* exported handleSignoutClick */

        // TODO(developer): Set to client ID and API key from the Developer Console
        const CLIENT_ID = 'CLIENT_ID';
        const API_KEY = 'API_KEY';

        // Discovery doc URL for APIs used by the quickstart
        const DISCOVERY_DOC = 'https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v3/rest';

        // Authorization scopes required by the API; multiple scopes can be
        // included, separated by spaces.
        const SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive';

        let tokenClient;
        let gapiInited = false;
        let gisInited = false;

        document.getElementById('authorize_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';

        /**
         * Callback after api.js is loaded.
         */
        function gapiLoaded() {
            gapi.load('client', initializeGapiClient);
        }

        /**
         * Callback after the API client is loaded. Loads the
         * discovery doc to initialize the API.
         */
        async function initializeGapiClient() {
            await gapi.client.init({
            apiKey: API_KEY,
            discoveryDocs: [DISCOVERY_DOC],
            });
            gapiInited = true;
            maybeEnableButtons();
        }

        /**
         * Callback after Google Identity Services are loaded.
         */
        function gisLoaded() {
            tokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
            client_id: CLIENT_ID,
            scope: SCOPES,
            callback: '', // defined later
            });
            gisInited = true;
            maybeEnableButtons();
        }

        /**
         * Enables user interaction after all libraries are loaded.
         */
        function maybeEnableButtons() {
            if (gapiInited && gisInited) {
            document.getElementById('authorize_button').style.visibility = 'visible';
            }
        }

        /**
         *  Sign in the user upon button click.
         */
        function handleAuthClick() {
            tokenClient.callback = async (resp) => {
            if (resp.error !== undefined) {
                throw (resp);
            }
            document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'visible';
            document.getElementById('authorize_button').innerText = 'Refresh';
            await listFiles();
            };

            if (gapi.client.getToken() === null) {
            // Prompt the user to select a Google Account and ask for consent to share their data
            // when establishing a new session.
            tokenClient.requestAccessToken({prompt: 'consent'});
            } else {
            // Skip display of account chooser and consent dialog for an existing session.
            tokenClient.requestAccessToken({prompt: ''});
            }
        }

        /**
         *  Sign out the user upon button click.
         */
        function handleSignoutClick() {
            const token = gapi.client.getToken();
            if (token !== null) {
            google.accounts.oauth2.revoke(token.access_token);
            gapi.client.setToken('');
            document.getElementById('content').innerText = '';
            document.getElementById('authorize_button').innerText = 'Authorize';
            document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';
            }
        }

        function listFiles() {
            console.log("Listing files in folder");
            gapi.client.drive.files.list({
            "includeItemsFromAllDrives": true,
            "supportsAllDrives": true,
            "q": "trashed = false and parents in 'FOLDER_ID'"
            }).then(function(response) {
                console.log("Files listed successfully");
                var files = response.result.files;
                if (files && files.length > 0) {
                console.log(files.length + " files found");
                for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    var file = files[i];
                    var fileId = file.id;
                    var fileUrl = "https://drive.google.com/u/0/uc?id=" + fileId;
                    var imgTag = document.createElement("img");
                    imgTag.src = fileUrl;
                    document.getElementById("image-container").appendChild(imgTag);
                }
                } else {
                console.log("No files found.");
                }
            }, function(reason) {
                console.log("Error listing files: " + reason.result.error.message);
            });
        }
        </script>
        <script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" onload="gapiLoaded()"></script>
        <script async defer src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" onload="gisLoaded()"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I already tried changing the scopes and I read all that I could, but this topic is just not on the internet. The best case would be to don't use OAuth, but as I've read it's needed for accessing this API. Even the [Google Drive API Reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) only says this note, but it doesn't elaborate on this aspect:

```
Note: Authorization optional.
```

Could somebody please help me on this topic?

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to access a public google drive folder and get all the images from it.

If all you want to do is read it and its public, then you could just use an API Key.

> I read that you can actually do this by using the .json file from a service account.

Client side JavaScript does not support service account authorization flow. You need to use implicit flow in and request authorization of a user to access the ir private data.

To use Service accounts you must use a server sided programing language

Comment: @DalmTo 'If all you want to do is read it and its public, then you could just use an API Key.' So you mean I don't need to authorize? Because I could only get it working with that authorization code. Is there any sample code to interact with the API without authorization?

Comment: Yes you can get read only access to public data with an API key.  Authorization is only needed for private user data.      Yes there is most likely sample code for it try looking on the google apis js client library GitHub page

Comment: @DalmTo The interesting thing is that I can't seem to find any code without authentication, and also when I remove the authentication from my code, it won't work. Also the Google API playground returns an error with OAuth off: [playground](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22q%22%3A%22trashed%20%3D%20false%20and%20parents%20in%20%27FOLDER_ID%27%22%7D) (with a correct folder_ID of course)

Comment: again play ground is just for testing.   if you haven't figured it out by Monday poke me again and I will try to find you an example.  This is the one time of year I don't have time to boot a PC and help much more sorry 